# How to use Pinnacle Studio 9 effects in newer versions?

Tags: effects

I've created many HFX transitions to use in Pinnacle Studio 9 but newer versions of Pinnacle Studio(e.g. 12,14, etc.) does not support it. I need to stuck with 9 because I need those effects so badly.

Is there any way or workaround to make it work in newer versions?